# How to redesign two buttons

Tags: html, css

I need help to redesign close and info buttons.

This is how this buttons looks now:
[image]

It should look like this buttons on the banner:
[image]

CSS code of buttons:

```
 body {
        margin: 100px;
    }

    .banner-buttons {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 13px;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .adsByNano {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 50%;
        color: #d075f4;
    }

    a.infoLink:hover .adsByNano {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #d075f4;
    }

    .closeBtn {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .closeBtn:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #d075f4;
    }
```

HTML code of buttons:

```
 <div id="main">
    <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
        <div class="banner-buttons">
            <label class="adsByNano">Ads by Nano</label>
            <a class="infoLink" href="http://nanointeractive.com/privacy" target="_blank">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
                <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea about the solution?

Comment: You could attach a jsfiddle sample also

Comment: Do you want to reproduce the visuals of the buttons or the placement?

Comment: @MateuszJ Placement you mean banner where this buttons should stay? - that code is in mess, that is reason why I didn't want to share that code, just buttons. 
Do you know how I can do exacly the same design and postion of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
body {
    margin: 100px;
}
.nanoSaturnBanner {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #EDEBED;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.banner-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    right: 0;
    top: -10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.banner-buttons .closeBtn,
.banner-buttons .infoLink {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #77CDE0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.banner-buttons .closeBtn:hover {
  color: #77CDE0;
}

.adsByNano {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color: black;
}

a.infoLink:hover .adsByNano {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #d075f4;
}

.closeBtn {
    display: inline-block;
}

.closeBtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d075f4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="main">
    <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
        <div class="banner-buttons">
            <label class="adsByNano">Ads by Nano</label>
            <a class="infoLink" href="http://nanointeractive.com/privacy" target="_blank">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! very nice, thanks!

Only hover effect does not work. But thanks I will try to solve that alone.

Comment: add this .banner-buttons .closeBtn:hover,
.banner-buttons .infoLink:hover { color: set color here like black or #000 }

Answer (score 1):

Here it is...

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
.nanoSaturnBanner {text-align: right;}
.banner-buttons {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}

.banner-buttons:hover .adsByNano {
  display: inline-block;
}

.adsByNano {
  display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #d075f4;
}

a.infoLink:hover .adsByNano {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #d075f4;
}

.closeBtn {
    display: inline-block;
}

.closeBtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d075f4;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="main">
    <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
        <div class="banner-buttons">
            <label class="adsByNano">Ads by Nano</label>
            <a class="infoLink" href="http://nanointeractive.com/privacy" target="_blank">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
                <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar! Do you know maybe where I can found better icons of this current which I am using? 
I want just to be different color?

Comment: You can use icons from here also. Its also cool site https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

about color you can change your own color.]

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!
I want to this Label I want to this label "Ads by Nano" will show on hover. 
Problem is, I change class ".adsByNano" to be dispaly: none 
And put on link "a.infoLink:hover .adsByNano { dispaly: inline-block; }
But hover effect does not work? 
Do you have idea why?

Comment: Thank you my friend, I didn't now for that jsfiddle.